# replace line in file with sed command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, sh

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
local name="url"
local line='{ "name": "url", "value": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/dir1\/page1" }'

local name2="protocol"
local line2='{ "name": "protocol", "value": "ftp" }'

sed -i "/\<$name2\>/s/.*/$line2/" /mydir/myfile
sed -i "/\<$name\>/s/.*/$line/" /mydir/myfile
```

myfile contain:

```
{ "name": "url", "value": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/dir2\/page2" }
{ "name": "url2", "value": "http:\/\/www.example.net/page" }
{ "name": "protocol", "value": "http" }
```

I detect a problem with `/` symbol in value field with my sed command. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your files have `/` all over the place its better to **use an alternate regex delimiter**; it is supported by sed.

```
sed -i "/\<$name2\>/s|.*|$line2|" /mydir/myfile
sed -i "/\<$name\>/s|.*|$line|" /mydir/myfile
```

Comment: the problem I have other values like `ftp|http`, in this case how to do it?

Comment: You can use: `sed -i "/<$name2\>/s~.*~$line2~" /mydir/myfile` as I said any character works even control characters.

Comment: can I found another command to do this, independently of my value content and name

Answer (score 2):

Use a different separator like this:

```
sed -i "/\<$name2\>/s%.*%$line2%" /mydir/myfile
```

For example, this is a dump I did just now:

```
printf "eins x eins\nzwei x zwei\nabc x abc\ndef x def\n" | sed "/abc/s%x%y%"
```

It prints:

```
eins x eins
zwei x zwei
abc y abc
def x def
```

As you can see, just the line containing `abc` gets modified by the `s` command.

Instead of the `%` sign you can use any character *which does not appear in the value you want to replace*.  Keep that in mind.  You also can use `_` or `⌴` or `;` or a letter, a number, whatever you like.  It just mustn't appear in the value.